# Sql backup to network drive

Tags: sql, networking, backup, drive

I have created a sql job with 2 steps to create a db backup i.e., 1st step to get the db backup and second step to copy the db backup to network drive.

- 1st Step success.
- 2nd step fails.

In 2step am giving type as `operating system(cmdExec)` and in command line i mentioned as 
`robocopy <soure> <destination>` but it throuws the Error.

```
Error:-The process could not be created for step 2 of job 0x7847DBA2AFA7D149A5ED24AA8B3B9FA6 (reason: The system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed.
```

Quick help is highly appreciated.

Comment: oops it given an Error after giving source and destination in double quotes.

Comment: Error:ROBOCOPY::Robust File Copy for Windows  Started ERROR 5  Getting File System Type of Destination \\CMF-5CG4TM1\Backup\  Access is denied. Source : C:\Windows\system32\ D:\Test_Networkcopy\       Dest - \\CMF-5CG4TM1\Backup\ Files : *.* Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30     /05/28 16:10:11 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory C:\Windows\system32\ D:\Test_Networkcopy\  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.  Process Exit Code 16.  The step failed.
Syntax:robocopy " D:\Test_Networkcopy"  "\\CMF-5CG4TM1\Backup"

Comment: For your information if i create batch file with the sytnax if executes success without any issues.robocopy D:\Test_Networkcopy \\CMF-5CG4TM1\Backup

Comment: Update the question with a proper formatting instead of adding comments. It'll be easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I can think of:

1. Make sure that the path in the command is fully qualified (C:... etc) and wrap it in double quotes to avoid issues with spaces in path names. Paste the path into a command window and make sure Robocopy opens OK.
2. Make sure that the account that the SQL Server instance is running under (probably Network Service) has access to the robocopy executable.

Comment: oops it given an Error after giving source and destination in double quotes.

Comment: OK, can you paste what you have as the command?

Comment: I given above you want me to given Command and Error once??

Comment: Well you're getting "Access is denied" to the destination - I assume \\CMF-5CG4TM1 is a different server on the network in which case the SQL Server Agent Service Account will need access to that network share. If you look in Services (Start->Run->services.msc) what user account is the agent for this SQL instance running under? It's probably Network Service in which case I would change it to be a user account on the network that has sufficient access to that share. Avoid using an Administrator account though, just in case.

Comment: i cleared that access issue,i checked the user used by sql server agent and i provided admin rights to that user to the destination and source and destination are both on same domain and same network.

Comment: for your information that sql agent is using my credentials

Comment: OK, good. What's the error message look like now? Running it in a batch file the security context is your own account (or admin) so have you checked that the Agent service also has access to the source path?

Comment: Ha! Our comments keep crossing over - OK so we can rule out security on the source location.

Comment: i didnt get what your saying

Comment: The user which i am using is my account(am having admin rights on server),so how to resolve it now?

Comment: What error message are you now getting?

Comment: Source : D:\Test_Networkcopy\       Dest - \\CMF-5CG4TM1\Backup\        Files : *.*           Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------  2013/05/28 16:16:20 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Creating Destination Directory \\CMF-5CG4TM1\Backup\  Access is denied.  Process Exit Code 16.  The step failed.

Comment: am getting the above error,if u still say access issue,please let me know where the permissions need to provide so that i will change the rights and re-try

Comment: \\CMF-5CG4TM1\Backup\ Access is denied - you still don't have access to that location. When you changed the Agent Service credentials - do you restart that service? If not, do so.

Comment: even i have restarted second time for cross verification and still getting the same error

Comment: Thanks Dazz for all the earlier comments but please help me to fix these issue i really need help in these case

Comment: I assume \\CMF-5CG4TM1\Backup\ is a network share in which case it will have different permissions as a share to those it has on the file system as a folder. If you haven't done so already, check the permissions on the share rather than the file system and ensure that the user account or a group it belongs to has permission to write to that folder.

Comment: I provided full rights to the user on \\CMF-5CG4TM1\Backup\ path,k can u tell me one thing.Please suggest me how to copy the backup file to network,my requirement is to automate the job.

Comment: Well the option away from moving it within the Agent job itself would be to have another service running which monitors the local folder and automatically copies new files to the remote folder. There are literally dozens of options so you're better off posting that as a new question as to which one is best.

Comment: what is the another service your talking about which copies the new files to remote folder?

Comment: Dazz as your aware of my problem please suggest me the solution if i post new Question agian i have to explain my problem to new person please i request you to kindly guide me to copy the backup to network drive.

Comment: If it's for personal use then I'd suggest Crashplan Free. If it's for business use then you'll likely need a licence - in which case Syncovery is a good option. You may want to look at SyncToy too, this is a free MS product which I think can be made to work as a service but can also be driven from the command line so that could be an option too if you can get it to cache the credentials else you could end up in the same situation as you are with Robocopy. I wouldn't recommend diving into any one solution though, take a few minutes to research your options and see what fits your situation best.

Comment: so your suggestion is to user the tool right ?

Comment: Yes, as you can't seem to get the permissions quite right I would suggest something like Syncovery which you can get working and leave running on the server and then just backup the DB inside the Agent job. That siad though, whatever you use will need the right permissions to the destination else you will hit the same problems. Here is a tutorial on share permissions which may help http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Share-Permissions.html

Comment: Thank you very much Dazz for the help now am able to copy the backup to network using the robocopy option.

Comment: Thanks very much now am marking the answer as accepted thanks once again

Comment: That's great - out of interest and for anyone else looking in the future, what did you change?

Comment: but now am getting only one issue am able to copy the backup to destination(Share) but still the message states as job fail,can you please help me to fix that how to show the status to success

Comment: Earlier i have given the permission using the Security tab and now i shared the path using the share option which solved the issue.

Comment: Dazz can you please help how to change the exit message of robocopy it copies the files to network but exit message is getting as failed

Comment: Robocopy returns different exit codes depending on what it hasn't or hasn't done (http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html). In your case you would expect it and want it to have always copied files so where you define the step for the job set the "Process exit code or a successful command:" to 1 rather than the default 0

Comment: Yup but no luck i set the process code to 1 but still the message states as failed

Comment: Add a new file to the source directory (just a small text file or something) then run the robocopy command in a command window and check what the exit code is

Comment: where i can see the exit code in command prompt?

Comment: in command prompt not able to see any thing like exit code

Comment: Hmmm, try appending " ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQ 1 exit 1 ELSE exit 99" without the double quote to to end of your robocopy command

Comment: Note that there is a space before the ^

Comment: it gives w:30 in options

Comment: Options : /S /E /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

Comment: Sorry, try wrapping the robocopy command and in brackets so, "(robocopy command and parameters) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQ 1 exit 1 ELSE exit 99" without the double quotes.

Comment: sry it gives a message "was unexpected at this time"

Comment: I've done a bit of research for you and it looks like you'd be better off calling robocopy in a batch file and then call the batch file from your agent job. In your batch file you can then EXIT ERRORLEVEL which will be 1 if files have been copied.

Comment: ok but how to call batch file in sql agent i didnt find an option to call bat file?

Comment: In the same way that your calling robocopy but instead of the robocopy.exe call you would have something like cmd.exe /c "c:\test.bat" - quotes are needed if there are any spaces in the path or file name

Comment: am trying like these "cmd.exe /d D:\Test_Networkcopy\test.bat" but it given an Error saying that (eason: The system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed.) but i execute it in command promt it executes successfully.

Comment: Dazz am able to get the exit message as successfully in robocopy after changing the process code to 3.Now my issue is resolved.thanks